# Any known issues with VS2013 redistributable dlls on i3 systems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, vcredist

I have just released a new build of our Command Ops engine, which involved a conversion here from VS2010 to VS2013. I have included the retail vcredist_x86 package and it all seems to work fine for most of our users. However, I have two users running i3 systems - one Win7 Pro and the other Win7 Home Premium. They both report the same issue in that the game app won't launch - in terms that nothing is displayed on the screen. The game app is not listed in the App listing of Task Manager but there is an entry for it in the Processor listing. After 20 seconds another two entries appear in the Processor listing. One of these can be closed down but the other two refuse and can only be got rid of by rebooting. They can launch one of our visual basic apps that come with the install package but none of the visual c++ apps.

My gut feeling is that there is some difference with one or more of the redistributable dlls. Hence my question about whether there are any known differences based on an i3 system. Any advice would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing I have seen different with i3 systems with these redistributables. Did you try with the antivirus disabled?

Comment: You should start debugging

Comment: Don't get the error here.  Don't have an i3 machine

Comment: Good suggestion re turning off AV